# drawing wind mixing in the open ocean

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a diagram showing the influence of wind speed for mixing in the ocean. Here is my attempt (apologies for the long code, I'm guessing this can be done in a much more elegant way but seeing as I am a relatively new to tikz, here is my best effort):

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,snakes,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 4in, y = 2in]
\fill [blue!20]
  (0,0) -- (0.75,0) -- (0.75,0.5)
    decorate [decoration={snake, segment length = 1cm, amplitude = 0.125cm}] 
   { -- (0,0.5) } -- cycle;

\foreach \y in {-0.1,-0.2,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5}{
\draw[blue!20,line width = 1.5pt,dashed] (0,\y) -- (0.75,\y);
}

% arrow for wind
\draw[->, >=latex, gray!20!white, line width = 3pt] (0.08,0.57) -- (0.48,0.57) ;

% draw eddies
\foreach \x in {0.04,0.19,0.3,0.38,0.65}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.05) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\foreach \x in {0.09,0.17,0.25,0.35,0.45,0.55}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.1) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\foreach \x in {0.03,0.19,0.27,0.338,0.42,0.51,0.6,0.69}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.2) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\foreach \x in {0.08,0.16,0.35,0.39,0.45,0.55,0.65}
\draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.3) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\foreach \x in {0.03,0.1,0.187,0.3,0.46,0.51,0.55}
\draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.4) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\foreach \x in {0.405,0.599}
  \draw [>=stealth,->] (\x,0.42) arc (280:0:.1cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);

\draw [>=stealth,->] (0.26,0.31) arc (280:0:.2cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0.1,0.2) arc (160:0:.2cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0.6,0.1) arc (180:0:.2cm) -- +(283:0.05cm);
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0.35,0.4) arc (280:0:.2cm) -- +(283:0.01cm);
\draw [>=stealth,->] (0.5,0.05) arc (283:0:.2cm) -- +(280:0.01cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which illustrates how wind results in mixing in the upper ocean. My question is, could anyone suggest a way of making this diagram look more professional, or 'better looking'? I hope to include it in a scientific review, and at the moment it does not look that impressive. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the pic command, first used on page 45.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I'm not entirely sure what exactly you need to show or what exactly the underlying science is, it is difficult to do anything terribly transformative to the diagram. However, here are some tentative suggestions:

- Make the wind arrow darker both to tie it to the arrows showing the eddies and to ensure it survives printing, photocopying etc. Pale grey looks good for wind but will not survive the rigours of institutional duplication processes. (At least, it wouldn't survive them here - your institution may be better equipped but if your report may be read elsewhere, you can't count on this.)
- Maybe use a shading to convey the increasing depth of the ocean.
- Use `pics` to streamline the creation of eddies (as suggested in John Kormylo's comment).
- Adjust the dashed lines a bit so they are less regular, thinner but longer and blend a bit better with the deeper ocean colour now in place.

That gives something like this:

[image: fancier ocean?]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      x = 100mm,% better to stick to either imperial or metric measurements since it makes it easier to keep things consistent [translation: I find it hard to think in both at the same time and fairly hard to think in imperial for lengths at all!]
      y = 50mm,
      pics/eddy/.style n args={4}{%
        code={
          \path [>=stealth, ->, draw=black, pic actions] (0,0) arc (#1:0:#2) -- +(#3:#4);
        }
      },
    ]
    \begin{scope}% eliminate squared off part of ocean at left, also use a shading to convey the idea of ocean depth
        \clip (0,-.575) -- (0.75,-.575) -- (0.75,0.525) -- (0,.525) -- cycle;
        \path [bottom color=blue!80!green!15!black, top color=blue!20!green!20, middle color=blue!80!green]
          (-.05,-.575) -- (0.8,-.575) -- (0.8,0.5)
          decorate [decoration={snake, segment length = 1cm, amplitude = 0.125cm}]
          { -- (-.05,0.5) } -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \foreach \y [count=\yno] in {-0.1,-0.15,...,-0.55}{% do you need these at all? I'm not clear what they are meant to convey exactly
      \draw[blue!20, opacity=.65, line width = .5pt, dashed, dash phase=2*\yno mm, dash pattern=on 3.5mm off 1.25mm] (0,\y) -- (0.75,\y);
    }

    % arrow for wind
    \draw[->, >=latex, draw=darkgray, line width=3pt] (0.08,0.57) -- (0.48,0.57) ;% make this darker - if people print or photocopy your report, you don't want the arrow to disappear

    % draw eddies
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l/\m/\n in {%
      0.04/0.05/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.19, 0.3, 0.38, 0.65,
      0.09/0.1/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55,
      0.03/.2/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.19, 0.27, 0.338, 0.42, 0.51, 0.6, 0.69,
      0.08/.3/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.16, 0.35, 0.39, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65,
      0.03/.4/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.1, 0.187, 0.3, 0.46, 0.51, 0.55,
      0.405/.42/280/1mm/283/.5mm, 0.599,
      0.26/0.31/280/.2cm/283/0.05cm,
      0.1/0.2/160/.2cm/283/0.05cm,
      0.6/0.1/180/.2cm/283/0.05cm,
      0.35/0.4/280/.2cm/283/0.01cm,
      0.5/0.05/283/.2cm/280/0.01cm}
      {%
        \ifx\j\i
          \pic at (\i,\myj) {eddy={\myk}{\myl}{\mym}{\myn}};
        \else
          \pic at (\i,\j) {eddy={\k}{\l}{\m}{\n}};
          \global\let\myj\j
          \global\let\myk\k
          \global\let\myl\l
          \global\let\mym\m
          \global\let\myn\n
        \fi
      }

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would then think about the following:

- Are the dashed lines needed? I'm not sure what they should convey but I find them rather confusing. (Is the idea that the wind goes straight through this bit of ocean rather than turning it? Presumably not...) Can the lack of arrows establish stillness now that the shading is in place? If so, can you just drop the dashed lines?
- Is it significant that all of the eddy arrows end at the same point in the arc and begin at roughly the same point? It looks to me as if the force is coming from within the ocean rather than from the wind since most of the directions all seem to begin by opposing the wind direction, and none of them seem to be in line with it. Maybe this is intended and, if so, that's obviously great. If not, I'd rethink the directions a bit.

This might give you something like this:

[image: more mixed up ocean]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      x = 100mm,% better to stick to either imperial or metric measurements since it makes it easier to keep things consistent [translation: I find it hard to think in both at the same time and fairly hard to think in imperial for lengths at all!]
      y = 50mm,
      pics/eddy/.style n args={5}{%
        code={
          \path [>=stealth, ->, draw=black, pic actions] (0,0) arc (#1:#2:#3) -- +(#4:#5);
        }
      },
    ]
    \begin{scope}% eliminate squared off part of ocean at left, also use a shading to convey the idea of ocean depth
        \clip (0,-.575) -- (0.75,-.575) -- (0.75,0.525) -- (0,.525) -- cycle;
        \path [bottom color=blue!80!green!15!black, top color=blue!20!green!20, middle color=blue!80!green]
          (-.05,-.575) -- (0.8,-.575) -- (0.8,0.5)
          decorate [decoration={snake, segment length = 1cm, amplitude = 0.125cm}]
          { -- (-.05,0.5) } -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    % arrow for wind
    \draw[->, >=latex, draw=darkgray, line width=3pt] (0.08,0.57) -- (0.48,0.57) ;% make this darker - if people print or photocopy your report, you don't want the arrow to disappear

    % draw eddies
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\mycount] in {%
      0.04/0.05/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.3, 0.38, 0.65,
      0.09/0.1/1mm/.5mm, 0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55,
      0.03/.2/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.27, 0.338, 0.42, 0.51, 0.6, 0.69,
      0.08/.3/1mm/.5mm, 0.16, 0.35, 0.39, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65,
      0.03/.4/1mm/.5mm, 0.1, 0.187, 0.3, 0.46, 0.51, 0.55,
      0.405/.42/1mm/.5mm, 0.599,
      0.26/0.31/.2cm/0.05cm,
      0.35/0.4/.2cm/0.01cm,
      0.5/0.05/.2cm/0.01cm}
      {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymodeddy}{mod(\mycount,4)}
        \ifx\j\i
        \pic at (\i,\myj) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\myk}{\mymodeddy*90}{\myl}};
        \else
          \pic at (\i,\j) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\k}{\mymodeddy*90}{\l}};
          \global\let\myj\j
          \global\let\myk\k
          \global\let\myl\l
        \fi
      }
      \pic at (.1,.2) {eddy={160}{0}{2mm}{283}{.5mm}};
      \pic at (.6,.1) {eddy={180}{0}{2mm}{280}{.5mm}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps it would also be appropriate to indicate the wind entering the ocean more explicitly at the top:

[image: show wind entering ocean]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      x = 100mm,% better to stick to either imperial or metric measurements since it makes it easier to keep things consistent [translation: I find it hard to think in both at the same time and fairly hard to think in imperial for lengths at all!]
      y = 50mm,
      pics/eddy/.style n args={5}{%
        code={
          \path [>=stealth, ->, draw=black, pic actions] (0,0) arc (#1:#2:#3) -- +(#4:#5);
        }
      },
    ]
    \begin{scope}% eliminate squared off part of ocean at left, also use a shading to convey the idea of ocean depth
        \clip (0,-.575) -- (0.75,-.575) -- (0.75,0.525) -- (0,.525) -- cycle;
        \path [bottom color=blue!80!green!15!black, top color=blue!20!green!20, middle color=blue!80!green]
          (-.05,-.575) -- (0.8,-.575) -- (0.8,0.5)
          decorate [decoration={snake, segment length = 1cm, amplitude = 0.125cm}]
          { -- (-.05,0.5) } -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    % arrow for wind
    \draw[->, >=latex, draw=darkgray, line width=3pt] (0.08,0.57) -- (0.48,0.57) ;% make this darker - if people print or photocopy your report, you don't want the arrow to disappear

    % draw eddies
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\mycount] in {%
      0.04/0.05/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.3, 0.38, 0.65,
      0.09/0.1/1mm/.5mm, 0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55,
      0.03/.2/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.27, 0.338, 0.42, 0.51, 0.6, 0.69,
      0.08/.3/1mm/.5mm, 0.16, 0.35, 0.39, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65,
      0.03/.4/1mm/.5mm, 0.1, 0.187, 0.3, 0.46, 0.51, 0.55,
      0.405/.42/1mm/.5mm, 0.599,
      0.26/0.31/.2cm/0.05cm,
      0.35/0.4/.2cm/0.01cm,
      0.5/0.05/.2cm/0.01cm}
      {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymodeddy}{mod(\mycount,4)}
        \ifx\j\i
        \pic at (\i,\myj) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\myk}{\mymodeddy*90}{\myl}};
        \else
          \pic at (\i,\j) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\k}{\mymodeddy*90}{\l}};
          \global\let\myj\j
          \global\let\myk\k
          \global\let\myl\l
        \fi
      }
      \pic at (.1,.2) {eddy={160}{0}{2mm}{283}{.5mm}};
      \pic at (.6,.1) {eddy={180}{0}{2mm}{280}{.5mm}};

      \path (-.05,.5125) -- (.8,.5125) foreach \i [count=\ino] in {.0882,.2059,...,1} { coordinate [pos=\i] (o\ino) };
      \pic foreach \i in {1,...,8} at (o\i) {eddy={90}{-90}{1.5mm}{180}{.5mm}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Update

Since I see from your comment that the mixing gradually tails off, perhaps this could be conveyed using fewer and smaller arrows at lower levels:

[image: tail off mixing]

```
\documentclass[border = 0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      x = 100mm,% better to stick to either imperial or metric measurements since it makes it easier to keep things consistent [translation: I find it hard to think in both at the same time and fairly hard to think in imperial for lengths at all!]
      y = 50mm,
      pics/eddy/.style n args={5}{%
        code={
          \path [>=stealth, ->, draw=black, pic actions] (0,0) arc (#1:#2:#3) -- +(#4:#5);
        }
      },
    ]
    \begin{scope}% eliminate squared off part of ocean at left, also use a shading to convey the idea of ocean depth
        \clip (0,-.575) -- (0.75,-.575) -- (0.75,0.525) -- (0,.525) -- cycle;
        \path [bottom color=blue!80!green!15!black, top color=blue!20!green!20, middle color=blue!80!green]
          (-.05,-.575) -- (0.8,-.575) -- (0.8,0.5)
          decorate [decoration={snake, segment length = 1cm, amplitude = 0.125cm}]
          { -- (-.05,0.5) } -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    % arrow for wind
    \draw[->, >=latex, draw=darkgray, line width=3pt] (0.08,0.57) -- (0.48,0.57) ;% make this darker - if people print or photocopy your report, you don't want the arrow to disappear

    % draw eddies
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\mycount] in {%
      .23/-.2/.5mm/.5mm, .54,
      .05/-.125/.75mm/.5mm, .356, .71,
      .125/-.075/1mm/.5mm, .284, .5, .675,
      0.04/0.05/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.3, 0.38, 0.65,
      0.09/0.1/1mm/.5mm, 0.17, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55,
      0.03/.2/1mm/.5mm, 0.19, 0.27, 0.338, 0.42, 0.51, 0.6, 0.69,
      0.08/.3/1mm/.5mm, 0.16, 0.35, 0.39, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65,
      0.03/.4/1mm/.5mm, 0.1, 0.187, 0.3, 0.46, 0.51, 0.55,
      0.405/.42/1mm/.5mm, 0.599,
      0.26/0.31/.2cm/0.05cm,
      0.35/0.4/.2cm/0.01cm,
      0.5/0.05/.2cm/0.01cm}
      {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymodeddy}{mod(\mycount,4)}
        \ifx\j\i
        \pic at (\i,\myj) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\myk}{\mymodeddy*90}{\myl}};
        \else
          \pic at (\i,\j) {eddy={\mymodeddy*90}{\mymodeddy*90 - 280}{\k}{\mymodeddy*90}{\l}};
          \global\let\myj\j
          \global\let\myk\k
          \global\let\myl\l
        \fi
      }
      \pic at (.1,.2) {eddy={160}{0}{2mm}{283}{.5mm}};
      \pic at (.6,.1) {eddy={180}{0}{2mm}{280}{.5mm}};

      \path (-.05,.5125) -- (.8,.5125) foreach \i [count=\ino] in {.0882,.2059,...,1} { coordinate [pos=\i] (o\ino) };
      \pic foreach \i in {1,...,8} at (o\i) {eddy={90}{-90}{1.5mm}{180}{.5mm}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not an artist but I have some interesting application of `sin` function.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fadings}

\begin{document}
    \hspace*{-9cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
        \begin{scope}[ultra thick,-{Stealth[length=5mm]},bend right=20]
            \foreach\s in{1,...,10}{
                \draw[shift={(95-\s*\s,5)}](0,5)to(10,0);}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:100,samples=100]
            \path[fill=blue!10]
                (0,-5.1)--(0,0)--
                plot(\t+\t*\t/2000,{sin(\t r)*(1+\t*\t/4000))})
                --(110,-0)--(110,-5.1)--cycle;
            \path[fill=blue!30]
                (0,-5.1)--(0,0)--
                plot(.4+\t+\t*\t/1600,{sin(\t r)*(1+\t*\t/4000))})
                --(110,-0)--(110,-5.1)--cycle;
            \path[fill=blue!50]
                (0,-5.1)--(0,0)--
                plot(.8+\t+\t*\t/1280,{sin(\t r)*(1+\t*\t/4000))})
                --(110,-0)--(110,-5.1)--cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \fill[blue!60](0,-5)rectangle(110,-15.1);
            \fill[blue!72](0,-15)rectangle(110,-25.1);
            \fill[blue!100](0,-25)rectangle(110,-35.1);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[blue!50]
            \fill[path fading=west](20,-5)rectangle(90.1,-35);
            \fill(90,-5)rectangle(110,-35);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[thin,-{Stealth},start angle=90,end angle=-90]
            \foreach\s in{1,...,20}{
                \draw[shift={(105-\s*\s/4,-18-13*sin(8*\s r))}](0,2.4)arc[radius=2];
                \draw[shift={(105-\s*\s/4,-18-13*sin(8*\s r))}](0,-2.4)arc[radius=-2];}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is absolutely not my field, but if i understood it correctly, there isn't mixing in the lower part. I wonder if there is a gradient in mixing, or if it really is an abrupt change.

Comment: I know my figure is misleading. I tried searching *wind+ocean+mix* but found nothing. Perhaps KatyB could tell something more.

Comment: In actual fact there is a gradient, and you'll eventually reach a point where isn't any mixing (this would be the lower layer), the upper layer would be that regions where wind mixing can reach.